# Firebase: Add to Authenticated User

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-edittext, firebase-authentication

Please help, Can I add values to my authenticated user?

I have a createUser class where I have created my authenticated user.

```
public class CreateUserAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private Button btnSignUp;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);
        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on usage access for this app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is too short. Please enter a minimum of 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                //create user
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(CreateUserAccount.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(CreateUserAccount.this, "User Account Created" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(CreateUserAccount.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(CreateUserAccount.this, LandingPage.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });



            }
        });
    }
}
```

After the authenticated user has logged in, they can click on a page where they can input their children's names, which are written to a realtime DB.

```
public class AddChild extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String useruid=user.getUid();


//we will use these constants later to pass the artist name and id to another activity
public static final String ARTIST_NAME = "net.simplifiedcoding.firebasedatabaseexample.artistname";
public static final String ARTIST_ID = "net.simplifiedcoding.firebasedatabaseexample.artistid";

//view objects
EditText editChildName;
CardView addChild;
ListView lvChildren;

//a list to store all the artist from firebase database
List<Child> children;

//our database reference object
DatabaseReference databaseChildren;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_child);

    //getting the reference of artists node
    databaseChildren = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("children");

    //getting views
    editChildName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editChildName);
    lvChildren = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvChildren);
    addChild = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.addChild);

    //list to store artists
    children = new ArrayList<>();


    //adding an onclicklistener to button
    addChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //calling the method addArtist()
            //the method is defined below
            //this method is actually performing the write operation
            addChild();
        }
    });
}

/*
* This method is saving a new artist to the
* Firebase Realtime Database
* */
private void addChild() {
    //getting the values to save
    String name = editChildName.getText().toString().trim();

    //checking if the value is provided
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

        //getting a unique id using push().getKey() method
        //it will create a unique id and we will use it as the Primary Key for our Artist
        String id = databaseChildren.push().getKey();

        //creating an Artist Object
        Child child = new Child(name);

        //Saving the Artist
        databaseChildren.child(id).setValue(child);

        //setting edittext to blank again
        editChildName.setText("");

        //displaying a success toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Child added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        //if the value is not given displaying a toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

______CHILD CLASS________

```
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Child {
    private String childName;

    public Child(){
        //this constructor is required
    }

    public Child(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;

    }
public String getChildName() {
    return childName;
}
```

}

Is there any way of adding the addChild class db values that I have inputted to this user?

So that the authenticated user can view their children names that have been inputted? thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, after you authenticate your user you should get your users `Auth` ID

if your user is succefully logged into your app you should do this to put childs inside your user

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String userID;

// ...
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

after that , where you are posting your addChildren class you should call your user to succefully add data to the auntheticated user

```
mDatabase.child(userID).child("Name").setValue("Robert");
```

thats an example on how to add data inside your auth users.

where mDatabase is your database reference like this

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

happy coding

Comment: Thank you I am still a bit confused - do I add private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String userID;

// ...
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); to my addChild class?

Comment: is 'String userID' the name of the Child?

Comment: Userid will be the I'd of each user who logs in in your app, so the data will be saved to each user when they log in

Comment: I see WHere should I put this above?private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String userID;

// ...
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


  In AddChilld?

Comment: so i do not place it above?